# iCloud Account Not Supported In iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode6, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to test my iOS app that uses the CloudKit APIs with the simulator. When I try to log in with my iCloud credentials it says,

> **Device Not Supported**
>
> Your Apple ID is valid, but this iPhone is not qualified for iCloud.

[image]

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html) I should be able to log in as if it was a normal phone. I assume I must be doing something silly but I can't think of what I would be doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Apple ID you are trying to login with has two factor authentication enabled then you will see that message on the simulator. So far none of the simulated iOS devices correctly support 2FA for Apple IDs.

The work around for this is to:

1. Temporarily disable 2FA on the Apple ID
2. Login on the required simulators with the Apple ID
3. Re-enable 2FA for the Apple ID. (**Don't forget this part!**)

As long as the simulator has been linked to the Apple ID it will remain linked even if you enable 2FA. However, if you do a full reset of the simulator (eg. Reset Content and Settings) or need to logout then you will need to repeat the process.

Comment: iOS 9 (beta) simulator appears to support signing in with multi-factor auth

Answer (score 2):

It is theoretically possible: [Simulator User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW12) - Testing iCloud chapter.

However, some users [reported the same issue](http://www.ifans.com/blog/33613/) that Apple might limit the access per device.

Solutions from websites:

1. Try to "Reset Contents & Settings" of Simulator
2. Try with a different Apple ID
3. Check computer's HOSTS file to see whether any entries blocked the communication with Apple

Good luck.

Comment: Your Apple link is dead.  Is this the page you were linking to? 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW12